# Default Login Form for Secured Methodes in Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

Maybe I am thinking completely the wrong way. I want to use Spring Security for my web application and only secure some functions of my Controller class without specifying the URLs.

When I include the dependency `spring-boot-starter-security` everything is secured by default with a side default login form. So far so good.

Now I activate method security with `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)` and mark some of my methods with `@Secured("USER")`.

To have no security as default I define a custom `SecurityFilterChain`:

```
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().permitAll())
                .build();
    }
```

Of course I have a test user defined:

```
    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                        .username("test")
                        .password("test")
                        .roles("USER")
                        .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
```

I get a `403 Forbidden` on the secured methods. And a `404 Not Found` when I add this to the `SecurityFilterChain`:

```
                .formLogin((form) -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll()
```

Because the default login form is missing.

What do I need to do to get the default login form for the secured methods?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use Spring Security for my web application and only secure some functions of my Controller class without specifying the URLs.

Spring Security's web support is URL-based, so this does seem to contradict it's purpose. You can use only method-based security, but all of the behavior you're missing is expected because the filter chain is not in play. See [Spring Security filter chain](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/architecture.html#servlet-securityfilterchain) and [Method Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html).

> To have no security as default I define a custom `SecurityFilterChain`:

This would not be a best practice. Consider what happens when a developer forgets to add the `@Secured` or similar annotation. [Defense in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing)) would be a better approach, which is why Spring Security requires every endpoint to be authenticated by default.

> I get a `403 Forbidden` on the secured methods. And a `404 Not Found` when I add this to the `SecurityFilterChain`:

At the method level, the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` does not trigger the `AuthenticationEntryPoint`. This would explain why you don't get the default behavior of a redirect to `/login`.

When defining a custom login page with `http.formLogin().loginPage("/login")`, you are responsible for [providing a login page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/form.html#servlet-authentication-form-custom). This would explain why you receive a `404 Not Found`.

In order to get the default behavior, you need to specify something that causes requests to be processed appropriately by the filter chain prior to method security. For example, if all of your secured endpoints start with `/secured`, you should add that as an authorization rule:

```java
http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
    .mvcMatchers("/secured/**").authenticated()
    .anyRequest().permitAll()
);
```

But this still leaves a gap and **does not** practice defense in depth. So the best configuration would invert the rules and identify only URLs that should be allowed by default, such as static resources.

```java
http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
    .mvcMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
);
```

In either case, security exceptions would be thrown by the filter chain while processing requests to `@Secured` endpoints, and so the `AuthenticationEntryPoint` will be triggered. Keep in mind however that authentication and authorization are related but separate concepts. In Spring Security, it's the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` that is tying them together in a way that produces the expected user experience.

Comment: Thanks for your details answer. It pushed me in the right direction. I might be wrong but I thought it would be a common use case to have a public website with a small private user area. I ended up using a separated Controller with a RequestMapping and then securing that path. What I still don't like about that solution is that now I have two strings that need to be in sync. :(

Comment: You're quite welcome! I understand what you're saying and it is not uncommon (I would think) to have a public website with a sub-section of the site requiring authentication. I don't think this changes the thought process though. You could still have the entire website public under `/public` (for example). You can of course adopt the first example and only secure a small section, but it wouldn't be a best practice. Another common approach is to `permitAll()` an allow-list and configure it in properties. You can of course include `/` as a public page as well.